# Always take binaries from remote branch on pull and ignore conflicts

Tags: git, conflict, pull, libgit2sharp

I have a problem with git and binaries. I don't know why, but `libgit2sharp` always get's a conflict on pulling binaries from a remote repository, even they have not changed in the local repository. Does `git` provide the possibility, to override always binaries in the local repository when pulling from the remote repository? This would be very helpful and i don't have to change some thing with `libgit2sharp`.

The exact error message is:

> 1 conflict prevents from checkout

Thank you very much!

Comment: So are you trying to solve this using `git` or `libgit2sharp`?

Comment: I generaly use `libgit2sharp`, because we pull from a remote branch autoamtically in our application. But in a specific installation i get this error. When i use only git `git bash`, every thing works fine. So i want to tell `libgit2sharp` over some configuration file in the local repository, to always override binaries when pulling. Dificult to explain, hope it is a little bit clearer now. Thank you :)